# Installing a patch for RPAS getting the following error

Tags: oracle

I'm running a patch install in Oracle RPAS and getting the following error message:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/retek/ride/RideClassLoader
>   (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

has anyone seen something similar?

thanks!

Comment: that type of error usually implies the java class was compiled in a later JVM to the one you're trying to run it under (49 = java 1.5)